# Abrir JInternalFrame a partir de outro

Tags: java, swing, jdesktoppane, jinternalframe

Estava aprendendo a mexer com `JDesktopPane` a fim de utilizar em projetos futuros pois acho essa função bem interessante. Tentei chamar um `JInternalFrame` de um botão de dentro de um outro `JInternalFrame`, mas não obtive sucesso. Usei o mesmo código que usei para chamar a primeira, mas não obtive sucesso mesmo assim.

```
public class FrameDes extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public FrameDes() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    desktop = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
    jMenuBar2 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout desktopLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(desktop);
    desktop.setLayout(desktopLayout);
    desktopLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 852, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    desktopLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 428, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jMenu3.setText("File");

    jMenuItem1.setText("ChamarPP");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuBar2.add(jMenu3);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar2);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(desktop)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(desktop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
    );

    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(868, 488));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    PrimeiraPagina tela = new PrimeiraPagina();
    tela.setVisible(true);
    desktop.add(tela);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new FrameDes().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JDesktopPane desktop;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Esse primeiro código é da *Tela Principal* onde o `JDesktopPane` se encontra, as proximas paginas devem aparecer dentro dele.

```
public class PrimeiraPagina extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

public PrimeiraPagina() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setClosable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setMaximizable(true);

    jButton1.setText("Abri segunda Pagina");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(256, 256, 256)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(275, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(137, 137, 137)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(163, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    setBounds(0, 0, 697, 406);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    SegundaPagina tela = new SegundaPagina();
    FrameDes desc = new FrameDes();
    tela.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("mudar tela");
    desc.desktop.add(tela);
}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Esse trecho acima é do primeiro `JInternalFrame`, onde existe um botão que deveria chamar a segunda tela, mas ela por algum motivo não aparece.

```
public class SegundaPagina extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

public SegundaPagina() {
    initComponents();
    System.out.println("pagina mudada");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setClosable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setMaximizable(true);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Essa e a segunda pagina");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(172, 172, 172)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(204, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(144, 144, 144)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(190, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    setBounds(0, 0, 657, 393);
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Por fim a ultima tela, a qual deveria ser exibida no `JDesktopPane`, mas não aparece, note que coloquei um `println` nele para verificar se pelo menos era chamado e sim ele era, mas a tela não aparece. Qual o problema com o código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está criando desnecessariamente outra instancia do seu `JFrame`, e adicionando nele o frame interno. Neste método na sua classe `PrimeiraPagina`:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    SegundaPagina tela = new SegundaPagina();
    FrameDes desc = new FrameDes();
    tela.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("mudar tela");
    desc.desktop.add(tela);
}
```

Substitua por:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    SegundaPagina tela = new SegundaPagina();
    System.out.println("mudar tela");
    getParent().add(tela);
    tela.setVisible(true);
}
```

Se os frames internos estarão no mesmo `JDesktopPane`, um simples `getParent()` resolve o problema, pois ele retorna o container do componente atual, no caso, de um internalframe.

Outro detalhe é que você está definindo a visibilidade antes de adicionar o frame no `JDesktopPane`, isso é uma pratica ruim. Somente defina a visibilidade do frame interno depois de adicioná-lo a um componente container.

Comment: Obrigado, isso resolveu meu problema, me perdoe a dificuldade de explicar o problema

Comment: @MiguelCosta sem problema, eu já estava preparando um exemplo pra responder, caso você não conseguisse fazer um [mcve] do seu código, pra ao menos tentar apontar esse problema, que era o que eu estava desconfiando que poderia ser a causa :)